# How would I successfully call the colour changing function with an output?

Tags: python, tkinter

The function doesn't have an output. It runs with no errors but I'm confused as to why there's no output. I'm open to any other ideas on how to configure the `self.lbltochange` label's colour from Page1.

I have tried to directly configure the label from the command via `lambda: self.p2.lbltochange.config(bg="blue")`. This doesn't work.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.geometry("200x200")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (Page1, Page2):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.show_frame(Page1)

    def show_frame(self, page_name):
        frame = self.frames[page_name]
        frame.tkraise()

    def get_page(self, page_name):
        return self.frames[page_name]


class Page1(tk.Frame):  

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.p2 = Page2(parent="", controller=self)
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Cmd", command=self.otherchange)
        self.button.pack()

    def otherchange(self):
        self.p2.changelbl()

class Page2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.lbltochange = tk.Label(self, text="Label to change", bg="red")
        self.lbltochange.pack()

    def changelbl(self):
        self.lbltochange.config(bg="blue")

app = Main()
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a second frame Page2 inside Page1, but this frame is not displayed (with method `grid()`) so the method `otherchange` *is* executed and triggers `changelbl` for this invisible frame.

You can remove `self.p2 = Page2(parent="", controller=self)` and replace the call to `changelbl` by getting the reference of the created `Page2` stored in the parent/controller:

```
class Page1(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.controller = controller
        self.button = tk.Button(self, text="Cmd", command=self.otherchange)
        self.button.pack()

    def otherchange(self):
        page2 = self.controller.frames.get(Page2)
        page2.changelbl()
```